# How to properly count multiple criteria from ranges in a separate sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a master data table in a worksheet (worksheet name 'Data'; table range called 'MasterData'). This includes data about participants in a conference (name, nationality, etc.) and whether each person is attending individual events.

I am trying to make a dashboard type worksheet (worksheet name 'Dashboard') in the same Excel workbook that summarizes different types of data for a good overview and planning purposes.

Data table:

```
Name    Country Breakfast   Dinner  Concert Happy Hour  Field Trip
Sam USA Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes
John    USA No  No  No  Yes No
Matt    Canada  Yes Yes Yes No  Yes
Phil    Canada  Yes Yes Yes No  Yes
Marco   Mexico  No  Yes No  No  No
Julio   Mexico  Yes Yes No  Yes No
```

Dashboard event summary table:

```
Event   USA Canada  Mexico
Breakfast           
Dinner          
Concert         
Happy Hour          
Field Trip
```

As an example, I created a table (table name 'Events') in the dashboard worksheet where I want to summarize the number of people from each country that are going to each event, pulling from the data in the 'MasterData' table of the 'Data' worksheet.

I tried using COUNTIFS to count if Country in the 'MasterData' table of worksheet 'Data" equals USA AND the particular event equals "Yes". However, the formula doesn't appear to wrk correctly. See below:

```
=COUNTIFS(MasterData,MasterData[[#Headers],[Country]]="USA",MasterData[[#All],[Breakfast]],"Yes")
```

Am I using the right approach with `COUNTIFS`? What's wrong with formula I put in Excel? How would I rewrite this formula to give me the desired result - create a dashboard summarizing aspects of the master data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried to reproduce your sample data in the OP, and came up with a solution using the `COUNTIFS()` function, however it is not just same like the one you have tried since it uses `INDEX()` & `MATCH()` functions to return a range of `Yes` based on the type of `Events` and then applies the `COUNTIFS()` along with the `Countries`.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C3</kbd>

```
=COUNTIFS(
 INDEX(MasterData[[Breakfast]:[Field Trip]],,
 MATCH($B3,MasterData[[#Headers],[Breakfast]:[Field Trip]],0)),"Yes",
 MasterData[Country],C$2)
```

---

- `INDEX(MasterData[[Breakfast]:[Field Trip]],,MATCH($B3,MasterData[[#Headers],[Breakfast]:[Field Trip]],0))` --> Note the formula will return a range of values i.e. `Yes`/`No` based on the type of `Events`.
- The above formula is then used as a criteria range to check for the criteria `Yes` along with the `Country` Range & Country criteria in the `Dashboard` Sheet.
- **criteria_range1** -- above formula and `criteria1` `"Yes"`
- **criteria_range2** -- `MasterData[Country]` and `criteria2` `C$2`

---

There is better alternative which is using **[SUMPRODUCT()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e#:%7E:text=The%20SUMPRODUCT%20function%20returns%20the,and%20division%20are%20also%20possible.)** function in such scenarios.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C3</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MasterData[Country]=C$2)*
 (MasterData[[#Headers],[Breakfast]:[Field Trip]]=$B3)*
 (MasterData[[Breakfast]:[Field Trip]]="Yes"))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Your `countifs` formula needs to be adjusted.

1. the syntax is different from `sumfis`
2. the table naming is a little off, you need to reference the table data not the `[#Header]`, nor do I think you need the `[#All]` reference

it should look more like: `=COUNTIFS(MasterData[Breakfast],"Yes",MasterData[Country],"USA")`

Because of your data format you'll need to create formulas for each cell in your dashboard. As an alternative, if you take away all the `No`'s in your MasterData, you could just use a pivot table like so:

[image]

There are other ways to solve this, but this gets you going again.